# Convert string formatted as yyyymmddhhnn to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in an SQL Server database with a date field in it, presented as varchar in `yyyymmddhhnn` format (where `nn` is minutes). For example, `200012011200` would be `01 Dec 2000 12:00`. I need to convert this to a `datetime` value, but none of the `convert` codes seems to cover it. It's closest to ISO format `yyyymmdd` but that doesn't include the time part, so calling `convert(datetime, MyDateField, 112)` fails.

The time part is important, so I can't just strip it off. How can I convert this to datetime?

Comment: Why is a column called `DateField` not a `datetime` or `date` but a `varchar` column?

Comment: I didn't design the table, and it's years too old to start changing the structure now - not that I even have such priviledges. And that's not actually the name of the field, but I didn't want to use the real field names in my example (for the same reason I haven't provided real example data). I've changed it to `MyDateField`, but the naming isn't relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @t varchar(20)
set @t='200012011200'
select cast(stuff(stuff(@t, 11,0,':'),9,0,' ') as datetime)
```

Comment: Nice, much more concise than mine.

Comment: Thanks Kai for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, cast(SUBSTRING('200012011200',1,4)+
'-'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',5,2)+
'-'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',7,2)+
' '+SUBSTRING('200012011200',9,2)+
':'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',11,2)+
':00'+
'.000' AS DATETIME), 109)
```

This will result in `Dec  1 2000 12:00:00:000PM`

Using the 112 as parameter will result to `20001201`

Enjoy

UPDATE:

The `convert(varchar...)` is just for demonstration purposes. 
You can use this as well:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('200012011200',1,4)+
'-'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',5,2)+
'-'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',7,2)+
' '+SUBSTRING('200012011200',9,2)+
':'+SUBSTRING('200012011200',11,2)+
':00'+
'.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Output needs to be a `datetime`, not a `varchar`. I think this should work if you remove the outer `convert` though.

Answer (score 0):

My own rather brute-forced solution:

```
dateadd(mi, cast(substring(MyDateTime, 11, 2) as int), dateadd(hh, cast(substring(MyDateTime, 9, 2) as int), convert(datetime, left(MyDateTime, 8), 112)))
```

A horrendous contraption, but it does the job. Broken down from inside to out:

```
convert(datetime, left(MyDateTime, 8), 112)
```

Get the first 8 characters (`yyyymmdd`) and convert as ISO format.

```
dateadd(hh, cast(substring(MyDateTime, 9, 2) as int), ...)
```

Add on the hours with `dateadd` - characters 9 and 10, but needs to be cast and `int` before use in `dateadd`.

```
dateadd(mi, cast(substring(MyDateTime, 11, 2) as int), ...)
```

Add on the minutes with the same method, characters 11 and 12.

I can't imagine this solution could *be* any uglier without intentionally obfuscating it, and I doubt it's terribly efficient, but it does work.